Where I can write block and transaction specification?
I want to see some detailed specification of how block/tx on ethereum should look like. Ideally, see the diff between Capella/Deneb.
I googled it but mostly found only general overview articles, while I want a strict specification.
Sorry for dumb questions, I'm very noob in Ethereum
